# Partial differentiation and tangency

Tags: partial-derivative, conic-sections

$\text{Q}$ Write the equation of tangent at the vertex of the parabola $2y^2+3y+4x-3=0$ . $\text{My attempt}$ if I partially differentiate the curve with y then I get $y+0.75=0$ which is correct answer. now i am not much in calculus but I know that $dy/dx$ is the equation of tangent but here I have used partial differentiation . Am I wrong ?and is there more strong geometrical approach?

Comment: $y + 0.75 = 0$ isn't the tangent.  It's the normal.  Are you looking for the normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach will work but it will also make things way more complicated.  No calculus required.

Express $x$ in terms of $y$ and get:
$$x = -\frac{1}{2}y^2 -\frac{3}{4}y + \frac{3}{4}$$

This is a parabola that opens to the left.  How do we know this?  It's $x$ as a function of $y$, which means it opens either to the left or to the right.  And the coefficient on $y^2$ is negative, so it opens to the left.

The line tangent to the parabola at the vertex is, in this case, the *vertical* line through the vertex (vertical because the parabola opens to the left [as opposed to opening up or down]).  Therefore the equation will have the form $x = h$, where $h$ is the $x$-coordinate of the vertex.  So let's find that.

Now, just like with parabolas that are $y$ as a function of $x$, we can find the vertex of this parabola by analyzing the coefficients.  We have $a = -1/2$, $b = -3/4$, and $c = 3/4$.  The vertex is the point
$$ \left(g\left(-\frac{b}{2a}\right), -\frac{b}{2a}\right),$$
where $\displaystyle g(y) = x = -\frac{1}{2}y^2 -\frac{3}{4}y + \frac{3}{4}$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

If you take partial derivatives, $(\partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y)=(u,v)$, you will get a **gradient**, i.e., a normal vector to the curve in point $(x,y)$. From it, you can recover a tangent vector by taking $(v,-u)$ which has a null dot profuct with the gradient.

But it is much more direct to use the rule

$$2y^2+3y+4x-3=0 \rightarrow 2yy_0+3 \frac12(y+y_0)+4 \frac12(x+x_0)-3=0$$

which gives you at once the equation of the tangent in $(x_0,y_0)$.

Have you seen this rule with its different cases:

$$x^2 \rightarrow xx_0, \ y^2 \rightarrow yy_0, xy \rightarrow \frac12(xx_0+yy_0), \ x \rightarrow \frac12(x+x_0),  \ y \rightarrow \frac12(y+y_0), \ constant \ c \rightarrow c $$